# Do something after checkbox is changed JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I was wondering if somebody can tell me how I can check if the checkbox status has changed. The problem is that I'm using a bootstrap theme (AdminLTE) which gives me a fancy checkbox, but I can't put a onchange or onclick on the checkbox, because I will be kind of hidden underneath the "makeup".

So I'm looking for a solution that does something on checkbox status change (true or false), while you cant "acces" the checkbox with an onclick etc. in html.

Checkbox plugin: icheck.

The code for the checkbox:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">
  <input id="username" type="checkbox" class="minimal">
   </span>
```

Thanks in advance (:

Edit: Most answers here will work for regular checkboxes (Might be usefull for others), but for my problem there was 1 working answer. But I'd like to thank everybody (:

Comment: If you know it's `id` or `class` you can always use `eventListener` with `change` event.

Comment: can you specify the exact plugin used ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan icheck, added it in the question (:

Comment: @Kinduser thanks, i will look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an event handler for [`ifChanged` event](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck#callbacks).

```
$('input').on('ifChanged', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

You can choose the preferred event as you need, which is fired by `iCheck` plugin : [check here](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck#callbacks).

Comment: Though none of these answers seem to work, your answer does keep the plugin in mind. I put the code in a script tag just before the /body tag. Maybe i shoudl put the Id or something where the 'input' is?

Comment: @JeroenM : wrap it with document ready handler, or put it at the end of body tag....

Comment: @JeroenM : with document ready handler : `$(document).ready(function(){ $('input').on('ifChanged', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
}); });`  ..... or `$(function(){ $('input').on('ifChanged', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
}); });`

Answer (score 0):

check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dm3f7src/)
JS

```
$('input:checkbox[name=example]').change(function() {
  alert("Hello!");
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example" /> click me
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#x").change(function(){
            if ( $("#y").val().length == 0 )
                {
                $("#y").val(0);
                var a = parseInt($('#x').val(), 10);
                var b = parseInt($('#y').val(), 10);
                $('#z').val(a+b);
                }
            else{
                var a = parseInt($('#x').val(), 10);
                var b = parseInt($('#y').val(), 10);
                $('#z').val(a+b);
            }
        });
```